# Put liferay service builder data inside api?

Tags: java, liferay

I'm working with liferay 7.3 and following the liferay service builder tutorial for 7.2.
I want to put my guestbook entries inside an api so I can retrieve them else where. I'm trying to use the getGuestbookEntries get methods that you make when you follow the service builder tutorial but it's only getting one entry at a time.

```
@GET
@Path("/guestbook/{groupid}")
@Produces("application/json")
public List<GuestbookEntry> getGuestbook(
        @PathParam("groupId") Long groupId,
        @QueryParam("guestbookId") Long guestbookId) {
    
    
    return (List<GuestbookEntry>)_guestbookEntryLocalService.getGuestbookEntries(groupId, guestbookId);
}
```

Currently I'm using this, but it's not working.
Any ideas?

Comment: You could also check `remote-service="true"` in your service xml to generate remote services (not exactly the same as what you tried). Otherwise, you need to create a jars application to wrap your service calls and provide appropriate `@Path` settings

Comment: @AndreAlbert remote-service="true" is already set